# How can I loop through a dataframe to create separate Folium maps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dataframe, folium

I'm trying to examine the sushi venues within 5 different cities, using foursqaure.
I can get the data and filter it correctly. Code below.

```
city = {'City':['Brunswick','Auckland','Wellington','Christchurch','Hamilton','Ponsonby'],
    'Latitude':[-37.7670,-36.848461,-41.28664,-43.55533,-37.78333,-36.8488],
    'Longitude':[144.9621,174.763336,174.77557,172.63333,175.28333,174.7381]}
df_location= pd.DataFrame(city, columns = ['City','Latitude','Longitude'])

def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=2000, LIMIT=100):
venues_list=[]
for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
    # create the API request URL
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}&categoryId={}'.format(
        CLIENT_ID, 
        CLIENT_SECRET, 
        VERSION,
        lat,
        lng,
        radius,
        LIMIT,
        "4bf58dd8d48988d1d2941735")
    # make the GET request
    results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']
    venues_list.append([(
        name, 
        v['venue']['name'], 
        v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
        v['venue']['location']['lng']) for v in results])
nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
nearby_venues.columns = [
              'City',
              'Venue', 
              'Venue Latitude', 
              'Venue Longitude',]
return(nearby_venues)

sushi_venues = getNearbyVenues(names = df_location['City'],
                               latitudes = df_location['Latitude'],
                               longitudes = df_location['Longitude'])
cities = df_location["City"]
latitude = df_location["Latitude"]
longitude = df_location["Longitude"]
```

I'm getting stuck on creating the maps and I'm not sure how I should iterate through the cities to create a map for each.
Here's the code I have.

```
maps = {}
for city in cities:
maps[city] = folium.Map(location = [latitude, longitude],zoom_start=10)


for lat, lng, neighborhood in zip(sushi_venues['Venue Latitude'], sushi_venues['Venue Longitude'], sushi_venues['Venue']):
    label = '{}'.format(neighborhood)
    label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html = True)
    folium.CircleMarker(
    [lat, lng],
    radius = 5,
    popup = label,
    color = 'blue',
    fill = True,
    fill_color = '#3186cc',
    fill_opacity = 0.7,
    parse_html = False).add_to(maps[city])

maps[cities[0]]
```

For this code, 'maps[cities[0]]' brings up a blank folio map.

If I change the code to reference the row of the city in df_location, e.g

```
maps = {}
   for city in cities:
   maps[city] = folium.Map(location = [latitude[0], longitude[0],zoom_start=10)
```

Then 'maps[cities[0]]' brings up a correctly labeled Folio map of Brunswick with the corresponding venues marked.
So my question is, how can I correctly iterate through all 5 cities, so that I can pull a new map for each without changing the location each time? I'm unable to zip the locations because it needs to be a single lat/long to initialize the Folium map.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Could you please edit your code with correct indentation? Furthermore, could you please provide an example of `sushi_venues` DataFrame and the final result you want to get?